# Flutter Show context actions shortcut not working

Tags: macos, android-studio, flutter, dart

i upgrade android studio to version 4.0.0 , dart and flutter.
my flutter docotor is attached on the bottom everything working fine web android ios by one shortcut not working for me and its realy hard to work without it(before the update it works fine ),
the name of the short cut was show intention actions which capable to remove widget add padding column, row,stream builder etc...
now it called something else show context actions and its not working

** notice already uninstall flutter and dart + restart and nothing works

Flutter doctor:

[[image: Flutter doctor]]

This is what i am expecting to work:
[image: 2]]

Comment: For such a self-solved question, you should paste the solution as an answer then accept your answer yourself.

Comment: OMG, thank you sooooo much for posting this solution @alien123X   I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out how this got turned off.

Comment: Add the solution as an answer dude

Comment: none of the solutions posted in this question worked for me, I ran `flutter doctor` and there were no issues found.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The solution is go to android studio tab->preferences->Editor->intention->Dart->check  quick assits powered by dart....(same as the attachment)

[image]

Comment: This solution works. I wonder how it got disabled suddenly...

Answer (score 28):

This one work for me, on the bottom left corner, Dart Analysis-> Settings -> Enable Dart Analysis on the current package.

[image]

Comment: Superb! This one worked for me. Intentions setting was enabled.

Comment: Life saver, I'd have never guessed where to look for.

Comment: This is worked for me, the accepted answer did not

Comment: This is worked for me too, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

If the answer above does not work, disabling and enabling the Dart & Flutter Plugins worked for me in Android Studio.

Comment: Above solutions did not work. But your solution worked for me.

Comment: The above solutions did not work. But your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the Flutter plugin had an update available. I installed it, restarted Android Studio and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same thing, but solved it by refreshing the Flutter Inspector which was freezed at my first class.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, just hitting tab will reset things. In particular, Expanded seems to do this the most, and just in general when adding a parent widget with context actions.  Simple little thing, but good to know.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me (but they helped me navigating the Android Studio settings) and I was going crazy with this until I tried out `⌥ + Enter + Tab`.

I have no idea why does it only work this way and not simply `⌥ + Enter`, which is what is written in my Keymap, but I'm posting it here in case it saves someone the hour that I spent with this.

Answer (score 0):

The Intentions options in Android Studio settings "android studio tab->preferences->Editor->intention->Dart->check quick assists powered by dart" was already checked so wasn't the issue. I was able to get the 'Show Context Actions" menu working by making sure the name of my project app in the directory folder was all lower-case letters and matched the project name exactly in Android Studio. So, it was a project name casing issue for me and once they matached, I was able to see the Action intentions and wrap my Flutter widgets thru the menu.

So as an example, this would break the intentions context menu as a name: 'ChatApp' (folder name); but once I changed it to 'chat_app', it fixed the issue. Incidentally, changing the directory folder name of the project file SHOULD change the project name that shows up in Android Studio, but if it doesn't you can rename the two so it matches exactly. Hope this works for you!

Answer (score -2):

Strangely, in this case, restarting the computer helped me